# How to detect if a Symfony Bundle or Composer package is still used?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have started working on a Symfony 2.8 based project which has not been updated for quite a while. The final goal is to update the project to Symfony 4.

The project includes a few dozens third party packages and bundle using composer and I assume that many of these imports are not used anymore.

Is there any method to automatically detect which package/bundle is actually used by the project?

Answer (score 0):

[shipmonk/composer-dependency-analyser](https://github.com/shipmonk-rnd/composer-dependency-analyser) can **detect unused dependencies**. It scans your whole project and detects used classes. Then, it reports all packages listed in `require` without a single usage.

Usage is simple:

```bash
composer require --dev shipmonk/composer-dependency-analyser

vendor/bin/composer-dependency-analyser
```

It also detects other issues like shadowed composer dependencies and misplaced composer dependencies, but you can ignore those if you care only about unused composer dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

For bundles, you can check `app/AppKernel.php` file to check which bundles are being used in your project.

For not bundle packages, you can use this:
https://github.com/Insolita/unused-scanner